# Registering a driver in linux

Tags: android, linux, device-driver

Can you help me in understanding the difference between platform_driver_register vs driver_register?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very obvious.

**platform_driver_register** is build upon **driver_register**.

> > int platform_driver_register(struct platform_driver *drv)
> >
> > {
> >
> > drv->driver.bus = &platform_bus_type;
> >
> > if (drv->probe)
> >
> > ```
> >  drv->driver.probe = platform_drv_probe;
> > ```
> >
> > if (drv->remove)
> >
> > ```
> >  drv->driver.remove = platform_drv_remove;
> > ```
> >
> > if (drv->shutdown)
> >
> > ```
> >  drv->driver.shutdown = platform_drv_shutdown;
> > ```
> >
> > **return driver_register(&drv->driver);**
> >
> > }